# How to render top level menu using material design

Tags: angular, user-interface, material-design, angular-material

Is it possible to create a top level navigation using material design tags (md tags). I am trying to render a menu which looks like below image using material design UI.
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43883400/what-is-an-example-of-a-material-design-angular2-4-menu-with-nested-dropdown-opt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a full Plunker demo for you that you can check out:

- [{ Here }](http://plnkr.co/edit/wZKRAyKcOtS6VoRAmEY1?p=preview)

---

the app uses the regular angular material2 menu with the `(mouseover)` and `(mouseleave)` events.